# How to add select2 function to newly added dynamic select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to implement select2 in the Html form it was working for the first element

[image]

But it was not working for the second element added dynamically

[image]

I tried my best to do this but I am new to JavaScript and select2

I wrote my entire code in this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

```
<table class="table" id="dynamicTable12" style="width: 50%">
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col" span="1" style="width: 25%;" >projects</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td> <select name="addmore1[0][project]" class="form-control" id="state" required="required">
                                    <option value="">-- Select Project --</option>
                                    <option value="A">A</option>
                                    <option value="B">B</option>
                        </select></td>  
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add12" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  </tr>
                            </table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
$("#add12").click(function(){
    ++i;
    $("#dynamicTable12").append('<tr><td><select name="addmore1['+i+'][project]" id="" class="form-control" required="required"><option value="">-- Select Project --</option> <option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
     $(this).parents('tr').remove();
}); 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js').select2();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure if the original code you provided was working properly. Because there was no element that has `.js` class as shown in this line:

> `$('.js').select2();`

However, let's get straight to the point. The reason the second or later `select` were not funcitoning is because when the new element is created, `select2` plug-in does not regconize this new element. Therefore, you have to reinitialize `select2` plug-in again. You can achieve this by giving the initialization code in a separate funciton, then recall it when a new element is added. Notice the `js` class and `reinitializeSelect2` fucntion in provided code.

```js
let initializeSelect2 =  function() {
  $('.js').select2();
}

var i = 0;
$("#add12").click(function(){
    ++i;
    $("#dynamicTable12").append('<tr><td><select name="addmore1['+i+'][project]" id="" class="form-control js" required="required"><option value="">-- Select Project --</option> <option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>');
    
    initializeSelect2()
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
     $(this).parents('tr').remove();
}); 



$(document).ready(function() {
    initializeSelect2()
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<table class="table" id="dynamicTable12" style="width: 50%">
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col" span="1" style="width: 25%;" >projects</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td> <select name="addmore1[0][project]" class="form-control js" id="state" required="required">
                                    <option value="">-- Select Project --</option>
                                    <option value="A">A</option>
                                    <option value="B">B</option>
                        </select></td>  
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add12" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  </tr>
                            </table>
```